# Grails - Quartz

Tags: sql-server-2008, grails, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use the Quartz plugin for Grails to schedule a job in a web app I am working on. Using the 
RAMstore worked fine, but I need the job to persist in our SQLServer database, which has caused problems...

I have changed the jdbcStore variable in QuartzConfig.groovy to true, set def volatility = false in the 
job file, and used the SQLServer code to generate the required tables in the database, but keep getting 
an error:

org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]

Have an idea it might be something to do with the quartz plugin not being configured for a SQLServer database,
but haven't found much on the web about it(mostly the full java implementation of quartz rather than grails),
and experimenting with config files hasn't helped.

Does anyone know how to get this working? And which of the various Quartz config files grails actually uses?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of the Quartz plugin are you using?

Comment: Sorry Joshua, I am not working on this project any more. Can't remember what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

I use quartz:1.0.2 in several projects.
I don't persist my jobs, I assign each job a unique name.
Then I persist the state of my job with a domain I make to track the state of the job.

example, the execute section of my job finds its state tracking domain using jobName, which is a unique value I load from a properties files for each of my jobs.
Then I pass the FileImporter instance associated with this job to my service that executes all the conditional states of the job.

```
        FileImporter fileImporter1 = FileImporter.findByName(jobName);
        fileImporterService.importWhileEnabled(fileImporter1);
```

My service is not transactional, because I want the state of the job to be persisted immediately.  That way, if I restart my app, the last state of the job is known, and I can continue from the point it left off.
However, I usually just reset the job state to make it start from the beginning again after a restart of the web server.

In my service I use

```
static transactional = false
```

and persist the state immediately with flush: true

```
fileImporter.save(failOnError: true, flush: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this property in the quartz.properties file org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?.